Thymeleaf: index.html page did not display correctly after upgrade Sprint Boot from 1.4.3 to 1.5.22
Recently, I started trying to upgrade an application in SpringBoot with Thymeleaf (from 1.4.3 to 1.5.22). The application started fine, but when I checked those html pages, none of them display correctly. After looking into more details, I found that in the index.html was missing something.
The following are shown portion of the index.html from both versions after Thymeleaf transformation.
link rel="icon" th:href="@{/static/console/img/favicon.ico}" type="image/x-icon"
View source page in version 1.4.3
link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/dev/static/console/img/favicon-e58edb9fec1d2c653aac22892a890626.ico"
View Source page in version 1.5.22
link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/console/img/favicon.ico"
It seems that href and src attributes are missing the suffix jsession id. Can anyone know what I need to do to correct that?

That suffix is not a jsession id, it is more likely to be the web resource chain filtering. Do you have these properties in your application.properties: spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/** ?

@WimDeblauwe yes, I do.

Where is your icon located? It should be in src/main/resources/static/console/img and the link should be th:href="@{/console/img/favicon.ico}" (So static should not be in the path if you reference it from Thymeleaf.

@WimDeblauwe That works. However, why did it (th:href="@{/static/console/img/favicon.ico}" ) work in 1.4.3 version?

No idea, it should not have worked :)

@WimDeblauwe Anyhow, thank you for your guidance on this one.

When the icon is in src/main/resources/static/console/img, then use the following in your Thymeleaf template: th:href="@{/console/img/favicon.ico}"
(So static should not be in the path if you reference it from Thymeleaf.)
